# Password dialog for ssh key not working

Tags: password, ssh, git

I am trying to test my AWS git code commit:

`ssh git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

But I keep getting a mac password dialog for ssh key. I enter in my password, but I keep getting `Saving password to keychain failed` error. Does anyone know what might be going on?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If it asks for password it means you have not everything properly setup.

You need to set a policy in AWS IAM that grants access to your user to CodeCommit repos. In that policy you need to indicate the resource (repo) ARN (Amazon Resource Name) you want to grant access or `*` for all of them.

Then you need to generate a SSH key using `ssh-keygen` and enter the contents of that key (the .pub) in the IAM Console section named IAMUsersSSHKeys.

If you need further help let me know.